# Aws Lambda noobe test function turning back html from some webpage

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I am writing my first Lambda function helloWorld. It works in AWS console,  but when I execute it locally with a Node http request it returns html from some webpage.

I copied the url to use from the console and I pass it to Lambda in the request options object as a url argument along with Content-Type attribute set to "application/json" as the only property of the headers.

I used the code below, any help with this would be great.

```
var full_url = "https://7wbo0aklv1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/helloWorld";

var headers={};
headers[ "Content-Type" ] = "application/json";

var post_data = {};
post_data = JSON.stringify( post_data );

var options = {
  method : "POST",
  url:full_url,
  headers: headers
};

//perform the request
var req = https.request( options, function( res ) {
  var responseText = "";

  res.setEncoding( "utf8" );
  res.on( "data", function( chunk ) {
    responseText += chunk;
  } );
  res.on( "end", function() {
    console.log( responseText );
  } );
} );

req.on( "error", function( e ) {
  console.error( e );
} );

req.write( post_data );
req.end();
```

Comment: Instead of it turning back a simple "Hellow World" it turns back html from some webpage that I know nothing about

Comment: May I ask what did I do to deserve a down vote? I stated the problem and provided the code

Comment: I mean you have to use node.js sdk. Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/

Comment: that code is written in Node.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you that you are doing it wrong. If you want I can provide an example of how to execute your lambda function locally with aws-sdk for nodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the difference was but I went back and used an example straight from Node docs and it worked. So thanks for all your help.

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify( firstCustomer );

const options = {
    hostname: '7wbo90aklv1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    port    : 443,
    path    : '/default/helloWorld',
    method  : 'POST'
};

const req = https.request( options, ( res ) => {
    console.log( 'statusCode:', res.statusCode );
    console.log( 'headers:', res.headers );
    res.setEncoding( "utf8" );
    res.on( 'data', ( d ) => {
        process.stdout.write( d );
        var context = JSON.parse( d )
        var body = JSON.parse( context );
        debugger;
    } );
} );

req.on( 'error', ( e ) => {
    console.error( e );
} );

req.write( post_data );
req.end();
```